# How to open file in django

Tags: python, django, file-not-found

I'm trying to open a file that is in the same directory as the app from views.

```
-app
--views.py
--about.txt
--...
```

My code to open the file is..

```py
def home(request):
    with open('about.txt','r') as f:
        about = f
    about = about.split('\n')
    about = '<br/>'.join(about)
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'about':about})
```

But I keep getting an error of `

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'about.txt'
```

After thinking about this, I thought of putting it in a static dir but it would still give the same error.

- I am still quite a beginner at django.
- Django 2.2.3
- Python 3.7.3

Edit:
I don't know if this is the reason... but when pressing enter for new line, it makes it on a new indentation.[image: example]

Comment: If a relative path does not work try an absolute one.

Comment: @KlausD. What do you mean?

Comment: relative path: `about.txt`, absolute path: `/home/me/projects/my_first_app/about.txt`.

Comment: @KlausD. Would using `~` represent `home`? or `home/me/` (I'm using Windows)

Comment: No, `~` is a shell feature and not a real filename. But there is `os.path.expanduser()` which can help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

You have to prepend your path with something like `app` to create `app/about.txt`. I have insufficient information to tell you exactly what, but here is how to find out:

When you run your app, the working directory is probably not in app. You can figure out what path it is running in by using `os.getcwd()`. For example:

```py
import os

# ...

def home(request):
    print(os.getcwd())
    with open('about.txt','r') as f:
        about = f
    about = about.split('\n')
    about = '<br/>'.join(about)
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'about':about})
```

As @KlausD. mentioned, your path is relative. Whenever code is being run, it is run in a "working directory". For example, if I ran `python views.py` in the `app` directory, the  current working directory (`cwd` for short) would be `app`. Then, when a [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) is given, like `about.txt` (which really means `./about.txt`, where `.` represents the cwd), it looks in the cwd for `about.txt`.

Comment: Hmm.... You're saying that `app/about.txt` will work because it is acting like `./app/about.txt`? (Also, that explanation helped a lot!)

Comment: @12944qwerty I forget what django uses as the cwd during runtime, but something like that. You might have to do something like `../app/about.txt` if it's running in another subdirectory of your project. (It's been a year since I've used django, sorry!)

Comment: Hmm.. I've tried this... `os.getcwd()` returns `C:\Users\me\Documents\python\project` So, I tried `open('\\app\\about.txt')` but... same error

Comment: @12944qwerty ah hah! The `/` at the beginning means your root directory. Add a `.` before that and it should work (`open('./app/about.txt')`)

Comment: nope.. maybe I have to use `\\` as I'm using Windows?

Comment: Hmm. Shouldn't be necessary. Just try it without that all together, as in, try `open('app/about.txt')`

Comment: If that doesn't work, try listing the directory via `os.listdir('app')` and send me the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196070/discussion-between-calder-white-and-12944qwerty).